# How to Apply shopping cart rule for group products if there child products are not in same category in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, category, shopping-cart-price-rules, grouped-products

I want to apply shopping cart price rule on category but that category have group products and there child products are not in same category. when i apply rule on group products then after i add product on cart i cant see discout because child products are not in this category.
so how can i do that if i apply rule on category then aule aplly on chlid products also whether they are not in same category.